# LED resistor calculation

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

How to calculate the resistor value in the design attached?[image]

Comment: Can you explain why you are using 5 resistors rather than just one? Can you write a KVL equation for the loop? Why do you have these exact two values of Vcc? This sounds like a homework problem so we will expect you to show significant effort and ask a specific question.

Comment: Im working on led board design for vehicles.i have seen this type of resistor arrangement in china led board.like above circuit in china board,vcc=24v ,5 resistor with value of 22E for led with vf=3.2V  If =60mA..Can you explain me?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm sure you can see that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome.

Comment: Thanks for your response ....Will post as my problem clearly

Comment: What is a 22E resistor?

Comment: http://lednique.com/electrical-theory-basics/ohms-law-and-resistor-calculation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to add up all the Vf (forward voltage) of each LED **at *your* design current** and subtract that from the supply voltage, then apply Ohm's law to figure out the total resistance required.

You can then split that into as many resistors as you want, say if you want to use small SMT resistors and spread the heat dissipation out physically across a PCB.

Keep in mind that Vf varies with current (and decreases with temperature), and that in a vehicle the voltage is more like 14V than 12V when the engine is operating. If the Vf sum is relatively high that means the current can vary significantly (much more on a percentage basis than the 15% difference between 12V and 13.8V. For example, if each LED drops 2.0V, that adds up to 10V for 5. If you set the current to 50mA for 12V (Rtotal = 2/0.05 = 40 ohms) then the current would rise to 95mA at 13.8V (assuming Vf stayed the same, in reality it won't be *quite* that bad)- almost double!

You might want to spread the heat out *evenly*, so use 5 equal resistors, or you might anticipate heat is more concentrated in some area and want to use unequal values to even it out- as long as they add up to the desired total, and each resistor is operated within ratings it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...It will be helpful for me ..If desired value is 1kohm for 5 led ,then 1k is splitted into 200 Ohm for each led  is it right?...

Comment: yes vehicle voltage will be around 15v ...i will keep it in mind during calculation

Comment: @VigneshVky Yes, you can split 1K into 5x 200 ohms. To decide if it's necessary just calculate I^2*R (where I is the current you pick). For example, if I = 5mA and R = 1K then the total power is 0.025W and even a single microscopic [1K 01005](https://www.modelithics.com/models/Vendor/Panasonic/ERJ2GE0R00X.pdf) (0.2 x 0.4mm) resistor can handle it.

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need a resistor between all LEDs, one resistor is enough.

To calculate it use the following rule: rule (voltage = current * resistance)

```
V = I * R
```

However, because of the forward voltage use

```
(V - Vf) = I * R
```

Thus (assuming 24 V), and 5 LEDs:

```
(24 - 5 * 2.7) = 0.03 * R <=> 
R = 350 ohm
```

If you don't have a 350 ohm resistor, use the first larger value to be safe.

It does not matter where you place the resistor, normally it's added either at the begin or end of the chain.

**Update**

See remark of Nedd below. The power consumed is

```
P = V * I = (24 - 5 * 2.7) * 0.03 = 0.315 W
```

Or

```
P = I^2 * R = 0.03^2 * 315 = 0.315 W
```

This is more than a typical 1/8 W or 1/4 W resistor.

So you can use one 0.5W resistor, or use two or more resistors in series with 1/8 o r 1/4W, but in any case the order of LEDs and resistors does not matter.

Comment: Thank you for your reply...Im working on led board design for vehicles.i have seen this type of resistor arrangement in china led board.like above circuit.. In that  board,vcc=24v ,5 resistor with value of 22E for 5 led with vf=3.2V  If =60mA..Can you explain me?

Comment: What two people downvoted this and what don't they know? The test is "This answer is useful" / "This answer is not useful". The downvoters need a basic course in electronics, and another in politeness. IF you have a problem with a manifestly useful answer, please share your erudition, education and incisive insights, that we all may benefit. Or ......... .

Comment: The use of multiple resistors may just be to spread out the heat and to make a thin string. At the above givens parameters (24V and 3.2Vf) the If would actually be 72mA, (8V / 110 ohms).  So if a single resistor were used it would need to dissipate over 1/2 watt, (0.72mA * 8V).  So to keep the light string thin and to spread out the heat they might be using 5 separate lower wattage resistors.

Comment: @Nedd Thanks for that addition ... I will add it to the answer

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I also don't understand ... I missed Nedd's comment but even then the answer itself was not wrong. Maybe because it seems homework.

Comment: I didn't downvote....but I think the reason is OP doesn't deserve any answer as he seems so lazy with putting zero effort in this question.

Comment: @Mitu Raj I thought that at first, but initially I thought the 5 resistors would make not much sense.